# Get exit value of CMD child process called from java program

Tags: java, cmd

In my java program I am trying to run a different program through CMD with its output appearing in a command window in the foreground and then analyze the exit code of the child program (foo) in the main java program. Unfortunately, all I seem to be able to access is the exit code of the CMD window, which is always 0.

The following is a snippet of what I'm doing:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.directory(new File(dir));
pb.command("cmd","/c","start","/wait","foo.exe",arg);
process = pb.start();
exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

but exitVal is always 0 regardless of how foo exits. How can I get just the exit code of foo?
I'm also pretty new to java so if there's a more elegant way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Most likely `foo` doesn't return the right value when it exits with an error. Why don't you give an example of `foo` that always returns 0?

Comment: I know foo returns the proper values because I can call it from the command window and then look at its return with 'echo %errorlevel%'.
What sort of example could help you?

Comment: One that always returns 0. Also I don't know how you're getting `%errorlevel%`.

Comment: For example, if `arg` is invalid foo will immediately exit with what should be an exit code of 1, however `exitVal` still reads 0 because the cmd process closed successfully.
And sorry, I meant when I run foo from the command prompt the windows local variable `%errorlevel%` holds the most recent exit code.

Comment: Then you're not reading the return value of `foo` but the return value of `cmd`. Launch `foo` directly instead of through `cmd`.

Comment: I've realized this. As I said in the question, though, I need to run `foo` through `cmd` because otherwise `foo` is invisible to the user (which is undesirable). This is why I'm asking how to access the return value of `foo` despite being run from `cmd`.

Comment: Yeah I should read the question more carefully, sorry. I don't know Windows batch but maybe by doing `exit %errorlevel%` after `foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by modifying one of the things I had tried before to account for windows batch being finicky. The solution was to send another command to `cmd` to tell it to exit with the most recent error code. Earlier I had tried this by appending `& exit %errorlevel%` to the command but `cmd` variables are only updated at the end of each command line, not at the end of each command.
To force update, I used `%^errorlevel%` instead.